# Unable to read JSON response Angular JS Ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

In Angular sidemenu project

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.basePath = 'http://localhost/iongallery/rest/';
    
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url : $scope.basePath+'ajax_get_data_client.php',
        data : {'operation': 'showMonths'}
    }).then(function success(data){
        $scope.months = data;
        console.log($scope.months[1].years);
    }, function error(data){
        
    });
```

When i Load the app 2 request got generated, one without any data `{}` and one with data `{'operation': 'showMonths'}` .

[image]

The request without any data dosen;t fetch andy response and the request with data fetch
`[{"month":"2","years":"2016"},{"month":"3","years":"2016"},{"month":"4","years":"2016"},{"month":"5","years":"2016"}]`

this json.

But, while unable to read the JSON.
Give Eror `TypeError: Cannot read property 'years' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$http.then() has another signature](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

> The response object has these properties: data – {string|Object} – The
>   response body transformed with the transform functions.
>   status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response. headers –
>   {function([headerName])} – Header getter function. config – {Object} –
>   The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>   statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response. so you need
>   change lines

```
}).then(function success(data){
            $scope.months = data;
            console.log($scope.months[1].years);
        }, function error(data){
```

into

```
}).then(function success(response){
        $scope.months = response.data;
        console.log($scope.months[1].years);
    }, function error(data){
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing extra data parameter while reading JSON  ` response.data`.